# stop jquery onChange recursive iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have jstree plugin I simply fill this plugin by selected node and post data with ajax in node-select method. Althouh I make a control with "letChangeTrig"
it call himself onChamge method recursively due to I refrest tree.. but I want to call this when user select only..

```
$('#tree_2').jstree({            
}).on('changed.jstree', function (e, datap) {
    debugger
    if(!letChangeTrig)
    {
        letChangeTrig = true;
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: params,
        success: function (result) {
            treeData_ = prepareObjectsforTree(result.Objects);
            resfreshJSTree(treeData_);            
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {

        }
    });
});
```

refresh:

```
function resfreshJSTree(treeDataa) {
    letChangeTrig = false;
    $('#tree_2').jstree(true).settings.core.data = treeDataa;
    $('#tree_2').jstree(true).refresh();

}
```

and this is my jstree refresh function which trigg the onChange method.. and post data.. after response back to success I call this again to rebuil tree with changed data but in this way it begins to call himself without users select evet and it fall into loop.. I need to stop it by logical control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery `event.stopPropagation()` method?
It stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Comment: Your event object is the e passed into the callback function. Try e.stopPropagation()